# Unhide/Hide rows in excel with a form checkbox

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a form created in excel which has rows [10:48] hidden and I want to make so that when you click a checkbox rows [10:48] are unhidden. I assigned a macro to the checkbox and using this formula:

```
Private Sub CheckBox45_Click()

  If CheckBox45 = True Then

  [10:48].EntireRow.Hidden = False

  Else: [10:48].EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

End Sub
```

When I click the checkbox nothing happen, but when I unhide the rows and click the checkbox it hides the rows. Which makes me think that only one of the actions is working. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Don't know if this matters but the form checkbox is in column D row 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you are hiding/unhiding rows on Sheet 1 and the checkbox belongs to sheet 1 of the workbook, then:

```
Private Sub CheckBox30_Click()  
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).CheckBoxes("Check Box 30").Value = 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows("10:48").Hidden = true 
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows("10:48").Hidden = false
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that within the sheet 1 however now its giving me an error that it cannot run the macro "Portfolio.xlsm!No". The macro may not be available(...). I corrected the sentence to "Portfolio.Sheet(1).Rows("10:48").Hidden = No.Value". Is there something I did wrong? Everything for the excel is macro enabled and I have other macros that do run.

Comment: For some reason this is still not working. I believe by this point its more of a naming error rather than a formula error, so I will give you all the info I have to see if its possible to fix.
   Private Sub No_Click()  
     Portfolio.Sheet(1).Rows("10:48").Hidden = 
     Portfolio.Sheet(1).CheckBoxes("No").Value 
 End Sub

Thats what i am using. The workbook name is Portfolio, the checkbox text states "No", is there a way i can check what checkbox number it is and use that?

Comment: @Josh You'll want to get the name of the checkbox object. If you right click the checkbox you'll see its name in the upper left box (just left of the formula bar). Usually it is named something like "Check Box 1" by default. THAT name is what does in the`...CheckBoxes("Check Box 1")....`

Comment: I found the name its Check Box 30, so I changed the name in the formula but its still giving me the same error. However other macros are still working. Any ideas?

Comment: @Josh I had some typos, I discovered that the checkbox doesn't actually seem to return true/false values, but rather 1 for true and -4146 for false. My Answer has been amended

Comment: Now I am not getting any error but nothing is happening. I reassigned the macro to make sure everything was correct and it should be running on that box. Could it be a problem that its a form checkbox and not an activeX checkbox? The activeX checkbox didnt seem to be working as in I couldnt check or uncheck it.

Comment: @Josh If you put a breakpoint in the vba, and you click the checkbox, does code execution hit the breakpoint?

Comment: It does not and now its highlighting in yellow with an arrow the first line: Private Sub CheckBox45_Click(). I am not that familiar with VBA and most of the debugging is not done by me, but right now I have to. Is this like a cannot call that name error?

Comment: @Josh okay, I think you are just stuck in breakmode. In the Menu on the vba editor, click Run -> Reset - then try your checkbox again

Comment: Gave me an error, says object required. I believe that could be because i am using the form checkbox instead of the activeX checkbox?

Comment: @Josh btw - I don't think activeX is the issue.I've got the code in my answer working on my test sheet with a regular form checkbox

Comment: Strange, I have made sure all names make sense but ill figure it out thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

The statement `ws.CheckBoxes("Check Box 30") = 1` will either return `TRUE` or `FALSE` which will either hide, or unhide, your target rows.

```
Private Sub CheckBox30_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("A10:A48").EntireRow.Hidden = ws.CheckBoxes("Check Box 30") = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. Using this code i get the same mistake of object required in this line: : Set ws = Portfolio.Sheets("Sheet1"). Any ideas?

Comment: Please update the sheet name on the second line (`Sheet1`) to the actual sheet name and then run the code as is.